# A word (or two) for people who explore for the joy of learning

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a card game, and I need a title for a card which describes people who travel and explore for the joy of learning and sharing that knowledge - a combination of scientists and explorers.

I'd like a name for them that doesn't sound too pretentious or contrived, but gets the point across.

Any ideas?

Comment: Indiana's father called him *Junior*.

Comment: *Explorer* fits the bill just fine. You can't be suggesting explorers do not travel for the joy of learning and sharing that knowledge.

Comment: I'm after something more scientific than _explorer_, something that evokes scientific exploration, rather than exploring for the sake of being first to go somewhere/do something.

Comment: I think *learner* would be the term for those who actually find the learning joyful. Exploring is just a consequence. To be specific, I'm thinking of these two kinds of learners in particular: *self-learner*, and *life-long learner*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pioneer** is not a bad single word: a person who is among the first to research and develop a new area of knowledge or activity.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pioneer?q=pioneer#pioneer

As you say two words may be acceptable, you could have **Pioneering Explorer**.

Comment: I went with Pioneering Scientists, which better fits the theme, but you put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

one possibility is **discoverer**.

[discover](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discoverer): to notice or learn, especially by making an effort; to be the first, or the first of one's group or kind, to find, learn of, or observe.

Synonyms: discover, ascertain, determine, learn

This verbs mean to gain knowledge or awareness of something not known before: discovered a star in a distant galaxy; ascertaining the facts; tried to determine the origins of the problem; learned the sad news from the radio.

Answer (score 2):

A more scientific term than explorer which might appeal to the OP is

**Ethnographer** : [An anthropologist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethnography) who studies different human cultures

> The descriptive study of a particular human society or the process of making such a study. Contemporary ethnography is based almost entirely on fieldwork and **requires the complete immersion of the anthropologist in the culture and everyday life of the people who are the subject of his study.**
>
> ...
>
> The description of other ways of life is an activity with roots in
>   ancient times. Herodotus, the Greek traveler and historian of the 5th
>   century bc, wrote of some 50 different peoples he encountered or heard
>   of, remarking on their laws, social customs, religion, and appearance.
>   Beginning with the age of exploration and continuing into the early
>   20th century, detailed accounts of non-European peoples were rendered
>   by European traders, missionaries, and, later, colonial
>   administrators. [...]
>
> Many ethnographers reside in the field for a year or more, **learning
>   the local language or dialect and, to the greatest extent possible,
>   participating in everyday life while at the same time maintaining an
>   observer’s objective detachment.** This method, called
>   participant-observation, while necessary and useful for gaining a
>   thorough understanding of a foreign culture is in practice quite difficult.

[Encyclopaedia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/194292/ethnography)

Comment: Many of the types described may fit your suggestion, but what about the polar explorers or those who traipse jungles uninhabited by people?

Comment: @bib I wouldn't call them ethnographers then, as I understand the term. If a jungle or a polar region is uninhabited, there would be no culture or people to study or learn from, unless a previous civilization had left some traces of their existence.