# Word for having a gentle joy for being diligent?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, titles

I'm looking for a word that describe a person for having a gentle joy for being diligent. For example, a person spends their time and effort to learn a new word every morning. He does that because he believes that his vocabulary will be expanded some day, although there is no clear evidence that he will need to learn that word. One day, he meet that word and can recognize it without asking what it means. He has **a gentle joy** because of that.

What is the word for that joy? The word should have the *diligent* sense in it.

**Example sentence**:
- What keeps you consistence on learning vocab?
- I give me a gentle joy for being diligent, a _______

I have checked all of these synonyms but all of them cannot apply. They don't have the joy sense in it: conscientiousness, assiduousness, assiduity, hard work, application, concentration, effort, care, industriousness, rigor, meticulousness, thoroughness; perseverance, persistence, tenacity, dedication, commitment, tirelessness, indefatigability, doggedness

Comment: What's wrong with using more than one word (do you have it on the tip of your tongue or do you just hope for it)? Also, what did a thesaurus suggest and of those why weren't they sufficient?

Comment: I don't know if we can consider it a direct duplicate, but perhaps you may find the answers here which relate to a word for a joy of learning helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/a-word-or-two-for-people-who-explore-for-the-joy-of-learning

Comment: @Mitch there's nothing wrong with using more than one word. It's just that I'm finding a name for a product so I like to keep it short. I just hope that it exist. The best one I can find is what I already found: "joy for being diligent". All of the synonyms I found can't apply because they don't have the "joy" sense in them.

Comment: @Rome_Leader thanks, but that question only ask for the person who have the joy, and don't contain the sense of diligence in it

Comment: Naming requests are out of scope for this site. Please see the [help].

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a succinct enough word or phrase for both gentle joy and diligence but "pride" and "accomplishment" are both words that express the feeling of having achieved something and that usually involves diligence.

Comment: sedulous or assiduous are both words for taking care great care/diligence in something. I don't think there is a word that also includes joy - you'd need to qualify it in context, by saying something like "Mark enjoyed being sedulous".

Comment: @Rome I always confuse sedulous with seditious

Comment: @Mitch they are troubling close in spelling, and I often have to look up which is which myself! :) I've been reading a lot of Salman Rushdie lately - he is equally fond of both.

Comment: @Rome_Leader also alacrity (what I think is the winning answer) with celerity (speed)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered alacrity?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alacrity

http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/alacrity

He learns a new word each day with eager alacrity.

Answer (score 2):

Gratify/gratifying/gratification contain a sense of moderate  reward (think gratuity) as well as pleasure

> - What keeps you consistent on learning new vocabulary?
> - It's gratifying

[Gratification](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gratification) W-B

> ```
> 1  reward, recompense; especially :  gratuity
>
> 2 the act of gratifying :  the state of being gratified
>
> 3 a source of satisfaction or pleasure
> ```

[Gratifying](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gratifying)  Collins

> giving one satisfaction or pleasure